# Why is Cake PHP bake creating views containing fields from the wrong table?

Tags: php, cakephp

**QUESTION**

Why is Cake PHP bake creating views containing fields from the wrong table and how can I get it to use the correct table?

**BACKGROUND**

I have a cake:

```
v2.5.1
```

... and a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_quotes` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` text COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL,
  `expires` datetime NOT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `deleted_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_mysql500_ci COMMENT='UserQuotes' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

... and its model:

```
class UserQuote extends AppModel
{

}
```

... and I bake like so (from htdocs/app/):

```
./Console/cake bake
```

... and I'm careful to select the UserQuotes controller from the bake menu.

**ERROR**

The view has the correct title for the UserQuotes table but the included fields and data are from the User model (and users table) instead of from the UserQuotes model (and thus user_quotes table).

Comment: In brief, even though the plurality is not correct, according to Cake conventions `user_quotes` would be a join table between `user` and `quotes` and you only have a `user_id` to relate to the `user` table.  You should probably review http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html.  In your case the table should probably be `quotes`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver A join table would be `users_quotes`, respectively `quotes_users`, as the names are ment to be sorted in alphabetical order.

Comment: @ndm: Yes, that and the plurality, so I suspect it is getting confused.

Comment: @AbraCadaver That would be a bug then, `user_quotes` should generally work fine. I just gave it a try with a fresh copy of 2.5.1, and everything is being baked as expected.